# $.getscript adding duplicate event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know whats wrong in code but i am not able to understand why jquery is doing that ,so let me explain my problem  with following code

```
 test.html
 #############
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-layout"> <!-- Header with navigation - Start -->
<button id="btnTestMain" type="button" value="Adjust" class="btn btn- 
 red1">Button test MAIN</button>
 <div id="injectHeaderMainHTML"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#injectHeaderMainHTML").load("/ui-test/test_page.html", 'f' + (Math.random() * 1000000));
       $.getScript("js/test1.js", function() {  
    });
    });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>


 ###test1.js######

  $(document).ready(function() {

     $("#btnTestMain").click(function (event) {
          $.getScript("/ui-test/js/test.js").done(function() {
                            console.log("script loaded");
                        }).fail(function() {
                            console.log('problem in loading test js');
                        });
    });

  }); // Document Ready Closed

 test_Page.html
 ###############################
   <button id="btnTest1" type="button"  class="btn btn-red1">Button test 
   1</button>
   <button id="btnTest2" type="button"  class="btn btn-red1">Button test 2</button>  


  test.js
  ###############
     function testFunction()
    {
       console.log("test function called");
    }

  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnTest1").click(function (event) {
        console.log("button1 clicked");
     });

     $("#btnTest2").click(function (event) {
         testFunction();
     });
  });
```

Now every time i click btnTestMain, it adds event listener to btnTest1 and btnTest2 , so if i click btnTestMain 5 times there will be 5 click event listeners on btnTest1 and 5 on btnTest2.
Can anyone explain why this is happening? I know how to resolve the issue but i am not able to understand reason for duplicate event listeners.

Comment: You have a script that adds event listeners. You run this script each time you press the button. If you press the button 5 times the script will run 5 times, adding event listeners each time. Why did you think it would **not** create duplicate event listeners?

Comment: Yes it is same as you writing `jQuery("#btnTest1").click(function (event) {
        console.log("button1 clicked");
     });`, 5 times

Comment: And for further clarification `$(document).ready(function () {` gets executed everytime your button loads the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time 'test.js' is loaded, jQuery adds the 'click' listener to the two button elements. The key here is that it will not remove any old ones, and that is why you are getting the duplication (which, in reality, isn't a duplication).

Comment: Ok ,that is bit strange as i was under assumption that it should remove old event listeners but probably that is probably intended functionality or wrongful use of getScript by me.

Comment: You are correct, it's intended functionality. We used to use the format $('selector').off('click').on('click', function() {...}); to avoid that problem.